# How to remove the unwanted characters from fluentd logs

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd, efk, fluentdata

Currently I am sending my Kubernetes logs to cloud watch using Fluentd, but when I check the logs in cloudwatch, the logs are having extra unicode characters. I tried different ways to and regexp to solve but no luck. Here is the sample how my log is in cloud watch

Log in Cloudwatch: "log": "\u001b[2m2021-10-13 20:07:10.351\u001b[0;39m \u001b[32m INFO\u001b[0;39m \u001b[35m1\u001b[0;39m \u001b[2m---\u001b[0;39m \u001b[2m[trap-executor-0]\u001b[0;39m \u001b[36mc.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver     \u001b[0;39m \u001b[2m:\u001b[0;39m Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration\n"

Actual log : 2021-10-13 20:07:10.351  INFO 1 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration

Comment: They're not exactly unicode, they're ANSI, but you may have some success by setting `env: [{name: TERM, value: dumb}]` in that Pod to make it believe the terminal cannot represent colors, but aside from that, you're going to have to get your developers to stop being "cute" with their log output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mdaniel, thank you it worked

Comment: Hi @balu,  as per the mdaniel's suggestion, did you able to solve the issue only by setting env: [{name: TERM, value: dumb}] ?  Thanks.